# Adding new feature in QgsVectorLayer with openFeatureForm leads to segfault?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, vector-layer

In a QGIS 2.18 plugin, I'm trying to create new features in an existing vector layer and I want to display the attribute form so the user can fill the attributes data.

The geometry is build before by parsing datas coming from websockets. Using `layer.addFeature()` works well for layers that does not have any fields constraints (eg: primary key).

As I need to write in Postgres/Postgis table with PK constraint, I want to use Feature Form to let the user fill attribute value and PK will handle by QGIS with default value. This way I also benefit from the settings that the user may have do for the layer fields (eg : combobox, default value, constraints, ...)

For that I'd like to use the `openFeatureForm` method of `iface` with my layer and my new feature like that:

```
feat = QgsFeature()
new_geom = QgsGeometry()# here I construct a geometry
feat.setGeometry(new_geom)
iface.openFeatureForm(self.layer, feat)
```

The attribute form show up as expected but when I hit the Ok button QGIS crash with segfault (core dumped) ...

Steps to reproduce in python console:

- Select an editable vector layer
- run this code snippet in QGIS python console

  `layer = iface.activeLayer()
   feat = QgsFeature()
   iface.openFeatureForm(layer, feat)`
- dialog show up!
- click OK button --> **Boom!** QGIS crash with segfault

I guess something is wrong in passing feature to the form but i can't figure out how to make it works...

for the moment I'm using QGIS 2.18, it's planned to upgrade to QGIS 3.X but for now, I'm looking for a QGIS 2.X solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find the solution!

The feature that is used to open the feature form needs to have the same fields as the layer

So this way, it works smoothly:

```
feat = QgsFeature()
geom = QgsGeometry() # Construct a geometry
feat.setGeometry(geom)
feat.setFields(self.layer.pendingFields()) # retrieve the fields from layer and set them to the feature
self.iface.openFeatureForm(self.layer, feat)
```

The segfault was probably due to the wrong mapping between the layers's fields and the feature's fields.

Like that, the feature form opens as expected and I can save the feature back to my layer.